# Show concatened composite primary key

Tags: mysql, composite-primary-key

I am working on the design of a database that will be used to get an unique ID. The "main" table will have a composite primary key by getting the id from others tables

As an example, consider the following table that illustrates the problem:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| PK_main_table| FK1 | FK2 | ...                               |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 102_245      | 102 | 245 | ...                               |
| 102_984      | 102 | 984 | ...                               |
| 98_298       | 98  | 298 | ...                               |
| 564_114      | 564 | 114 | ...                               |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I will wrote the following :

```
CREATE TABLE main_table
(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
FK1 int(5),
FK2 int(5),
...
primary key(`FK1`, `_`, `FK2`, ...)
);
```

Note that all the foreign keys have an unique ID and it is possible for the same foreign key to be found many time (as you can see with FK1='102').

I have a decent understanding of relational databases, but am far from an expert or even an experienced user.

My question is : How can I get the primary key ? I wish I could do a SELECT [something there] where FK1='98' and get '98_298' as a result.

Comment: "My question is : How can I get the primary key ? I wish I could do a SELECT [something there] where FK1='98' and get '98_298' as a result." - What is the problem in doing that ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do.  Do you want a `composite primary key` or an `auto_increment` (those are different)?  Don't concatonate `foreign keys` together to create a unique key.  Perhaps you should keep researching and redefine your question...

Comment: @Veverke I do not know the exact syntax to make the query. Do I have to `select primary key where FK1='98'`?
@sgeddes I have to create a composite primary key but I do not know how to display it (I need it to write on official documents)

Comment: This seems like you're working backwards to solve a problem that PK / FK relationships are already designed to handle for you.  What happens when a row is deleted off one of the FK tables?  Are you going to go back and delete that row on the PK table?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a new field "primary_key" add fill in with a trigger with the following code :

```
select 
id,group_concat(concat(`FK1`,':',`FK2`) separator ',')
as Result from main_table group by id
```

Then I just have to

> select main_table.primary_key where [my condition]

I do not know if it is the best solution but it works great like that.